# 404 Error Contact Form 7 on WordPress

Tags: javascript, 404-error, json

I just created a new website. Everything seems to work perfectly except the contact form. Indeed, the contact form is not working, and affects loading after one try. The chrome console gave me this information:

```
jquery-1.12.4.js:2 GET https://nameofthewebsite.fr/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/109/refill 404 ()
```

The website is this one: divorceamiable-mayet.fr

Comment: try to desactivate all others plugins to test if you have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

this is quite a common [issue](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/contact-form-7-wp-json-404-error/) with htaccess file blocking malformed un-shlashed url such as cf7 wp-json requests.

Therefore check your `.htaccess` file in your root folder to see if this is the case with your server too, find the section in your `.htaccess` that is adding a '/' at the end of requests

```
# Add trailing slash to the end of the link
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-json
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|xml)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
# End Adding trailing slash to the end of the link
```

and isnert the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-json` to escape wp-json requests just before the `RewriteRule`